# Primefaces Dialog Update Mechanisms

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I was wondering which method should be used to update a Dialog in Primefaces.
Are these two implementations equivalent?

1st Method: Use dynamic attribute in dialog

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton onclick="dialog.show();"/>
</h:form>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" dynamic="true">
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
    </h:form> 
</p:dialog>
```

2nd Method: Update dialog manually by commandButton

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton onclick="dialog.show();" update="dialogForm"/>
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dialog">
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

When should i use which method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dialog has not been loaded at all, both methods have the same outcome.
The first method tries to pop up the dialog, but realizes that the content has not yet been loaded. Hence the content will be fetched from the corresponding bean.
The second method opens the dialog after the content has been loaded from the bean.

The difference is present after the dialog has been opened at least **once**:
If you open the dialog the second, third, fourth, ... nth time, the first method will just let the dialog pop up, because the content was already loaded the first time.
The second method will ensure, that the content is always up to date when the dialog opens.

Comment: So using dynamic attribute just makes sure the content is loaded lazy. But after it has been opened at least once, the content won´t get automatically updated. The data won´t be fetched lazy a second time, right?

Comment: Correct. Therefore you have to update the content of the dialog with `update=...`.

Answer (score 0):

From the VDL--

Dynamic mode allows dialog to fetch it's contents before it's shown rather than on page load which is useful to reduce initial page load times. Default is false.

Seems like the second option would fetch its content on page load and then updated it onclick..
Doing twice the work for the same result.